# REST API Design - add / remove an item in an array field of a resource

Tags: rest

Let's assume we have the following REST resource collection endpoint:

```
/products
```

The resource looks like this:

```
GET /products/123
Accept: application/json

{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Shampoo",
    ...
    "ingredients": [
        "Sodium Lauryl Sulfate",
        "Sodium Laureth Sulfate",
        "Hydrochloric Acid",
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now, let's say I want to update the resource, and add or remove an ingredient to / from the *ingredients* field.
One way is to `GET` the resource, manipulate the array, and `PUT` or `PATCH` back. However, this is pretty chatty protocol, and it also poses scaleability problem, if the array is too big.

What is the best way to achieve this add / remove operation without having the source array?

I already explored the following: [JSON Patch Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)
But it seems the spec is not REST. It uses the same resource with different "operation" like representation, which is entirely different from the resource's representation.

I would like to keep as much as possible the same representation of resource for `PUT` / `PATCH` method as it is appearing in `GET`.

Here are my thoughts on the matter.

1. Change the *string* type item to *object*
2. Add meta field to the object called *$op*

So in this design, here is how the resource looks like on `GET`

```
GET /products/123
Accept: application/json

{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Shampoo",
    ...
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "name": "Sodium Lauryl Sulfate"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sodium Laureth Sulfate"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hydrochloric Acid"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

And now if I want to remove an item from the *ingredients* array:

```
PATCH /products/123
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "$op": "remove",
            "name": "Hydrochloric Acid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or add it back:

```
PATCH /products/123
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "$op": "add",
            "name": "Hydrochloric Acid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone has a better way? Is there some standard on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution would be to provide another REST endpoint for product's ingredients management. When you in addition provide links in a HATEOAS manner, you will be able to fully controll that array right after getting a product resource.

Consider this representation:

```
GET /products/123
Accept: application/json

{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Shampoo",
    ...
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "name": "Sodium Lauryl Sulfate"
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "/products/123/ingredients/1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sodium Laureth Sulfate",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "/products/123/ingredients/2"
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "/products/123"
        },
        {
            "rel": "ingredients",
            "href": "/products/123/ingredients"
        }
    ]
}
```

Having this you could add new ingredient to a product...

```
POST /products/123/ingredients
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "name": "Hydrochloric Acid"
}
```

...or delete existing one.

```
DELETE /products/123/ingredients/2
```

> What is the best way to achieve this add / remove operation without having the source array?

If you remove ingredients array from product's JSON representation and leave only link to it you are still able to add new ingredient right away.

Remove operation still need source array but you could download it asynchronously. In fact i see no point in deleting anything from array without having it first. How do you know that ingredient you try to remove is inside?

Best regards

Comment: I thought about HATEOAS, however my requirement is to support this also on a bulk of products. Meaning, PUT / PATCH on the /products collection without a specific ID. Regarding remove - let's say there is a "total annihilation" :) scenario, and I want to instruct all the products to remove certain ingredient, be it the product have it or not.

Comment: meaning, the same problem will now occur with the links array when ingredients became fully blown resource.

Comment: Providing support for POST /products/ingredients and DELETE /products/ingredients?name=IngredientName would resolve this problem, but I'm not sure if is this proper solution. I'm curious, how to design this case to be 100% accurate with REST convention.

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct style for REST. There should be a PUT / PATCH request on the /products resource collection, with a collection of resources in the payload, as in POST, it's just for each resource in payload also supply the "id" field for referencing which item to update. And here I want to understand, how can the ingredients be updated not as a total replacement, but incremental addition / removal.